# How to use InMemoryLeaseManager and -CheckpointManager for Azure Event Hub?

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to connect to an existing Azure Event Hub feed using Java. For my first steps, I'm adjusting the [Event Hub Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs) project, specifically the [EventProcessorSample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/Java/Basic/EventProcessorSample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/samples/eventprocessorsample/EventProcessorSample.java).

However, it depends on you having an Azure Storage set up which will be used for the `ILeaseManager` and `ICheckpointManager`; since I don't have one, I've been looking around and found the `InMemoryLeaseManager` and `InMemoryCheckpointManager` classes I'd like to use for my first steps.

However, the protocol for those is that they are first created, then passed to the builder to create a `EventProcessorHost`, and after that you need to call `initialize` with the created host`s`HostContext`. Here's how I do that:

```
    InMemoryCheckpointManager checkpointManager = new InMemoryCheckpointManager();
    InMemoryLeaseManager leaseManager = new InMemoryLeaseManager();
    EventProcessorHost processorHost = EventProcessorHost.EventProcessorHostBuilder
            .newBuilder(EventProcessorHost.createHostName(hostNamePrefix), consumerGroupName)
            .useUserCheckpointAndLeaseManagers(checkpointManager, leaseManager)
            .useEventHubConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString.toString(), eventHubName)
            .build();
    checkpointManager.initialize(processorHost.getHostContext());
    leaseManager.initialize(processorHost.getHostContext());
```

However, `EventProcessorHost#getHostContext()` is package visible, so the only way to get the above to compile is to put it in a class with package `com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost`. This will compile but not run, because the original Event Hub package is signed, so running this causes a

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.ILeaseManager"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

So I really have to wonder how you are to supposed to use those utility classes at all.

Of course I can a) implement the interfaces myself or b) create an unsigned Event Hub package, but both don't seem to be what's intended.

Am I missing something?